# Docker in IntelliJ IDEA for Mac not working

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, docker

I am following this guide:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/docker.html#d213398e640
But I cannot get it to work with my docker-compose.yml.

No problem following the guide and configuring my project. However it does not start when I try to start the docker run configuration.
[image]
All I get is a red box on the whale icon in the Docker tool window in IDEA. Hovering it gives me `io.netty.channelConnectTimeoutException: Connection timed out 192.168.99.100:2376`
[image]

I am running the latest Docker for Mac and I have no issues running in command line with: `docker-compose up`.

Any ideas?